# How to create shapes in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create one the following shape in css.

[image]

In the above shape how to create in css?

Comment: Try something. I recommend a border radius and a box shadow.

Comment: border-radius property is not taking css2.1

Comment: Try searching on the Internet first and then post a question. Search for: CSS rounded rectangle shadow. Then come back here and post the code if you have problems.

Comment: Just show a square in css 2.1 . No one cares it.

Comment: Here are some remarkable CSS shapes - http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dennisbest/bE2jB/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
   background    : white;
   border        : 1px solid #555;
   border-radius : 10px;
   height        : 125px;
   margin        : 20px;
   width         : 255px;
}
.box:before {
  background    : grey;
  border-radius : 10px;
  content       : ' ';
  display       : block;
  height        : 125px;
  left          : -10px;
  margin        : 20px 0;
  position      : relative;
  top           : -30px;
  width         : 255px;
  z-index       : -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but shadow is not coming..

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome only.. But in my css border-radius property is not taking. it is showing error line `border-radius is not known as css property name`

Comment: You must have an older version of Chrome. You can include `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;` and `-moz-border-radius: 10px;` to address older versions of modern browsers. Naturally, if you want to worry about every browser, you can. But life is short ... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement